# Node JS function parameters defined as object attributes - allowed or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, parameters, syntactic-sugar

I've been running Node JS code from the VS Code terminal panel and stumbled across a little bit of syntax sugar where

```
function foo(input_mapping){
  console.log(
    input_mapping.a,
    input_mapping.b,
    input_mapping.c
  );
}
```

can be instead declared as

```
function foo({a,b,c}){
  console.log(a,b,c);
}
```

where they're both called with something like

```
foo({
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:3
}); // -> '1 2 3'
```

however just recently I tried to run this same code through the terminal and the first { got flagged as a syntax error. What's going on? Why would one terminal take issue but not the other? Which JS interpretation is the correct one?

Comment: Update nodejs. It is valid and has been for a while

Comment: A terminal could take issue if its running an older version of node. Note that this syntatic sugar is called object destructuring, and its only been implemented on node 6